# Macro pattern not matching

Tags: macros, scheme, pattern-matching

[Full source](http://paste.call-cc.org/paste?id=a9867a49908b6ce97351bec24632385a0207ecc0)

So I have a macro for making objects, and it is used like:

```
(define ob 
  (class (a 10) (b 20)
         (set-a! (lambda (x) (set! a x)))
         (set-b! (lambda (x) (set! b x)))
         (foo (lambda (x)
                (* (+ a b) (- a b))))))

(ob 'a) -> 10
(ob 'b) -> 20
(ob 'set-a! 50)
(ob 'a) -> 50
(ob 'foo) -> 2100
```

I added another pattern for having public and private members,

```
(define ob
  (class private
         (a 10) (b 20)
         public
         (get-a (lambda (x) a))
         (set-a! (lambda (x) (set! a x)))))
```

and that works, but for some reason, it wont match this pattern:

```
(define ob2
  (class private
         (a 10) (b 20) (c '())
         public
         (get-a (lambda (x) a))
         (get-b (lambda (x) b))
         (set-a! (lambda (x) (set! a x)))
         (set-b! (lambda (x) (set! b x)))
         (push-c! (lambda (x)
                    (set! c (cons x c))))
         (pop-c! (lambda (x)
                   (if (not (eq? c '()))
                       (set! c (cdr c))
                       (error "stack empty!"))))))
```

The error message for trying to use ob2 is in the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the first example should not work either, and, in fact, I could not get it to work. I don't think you can use two ellipses on the same level. Therefore, it would be easier to define something like

```
(define-syntax class
  (syntax-rules (public private)
    ((class (public (?var ?val) ...) (private  (?var1 ?val1) ...))
     (list  (list ?var ?val) ... (list ?var1 ?val1) ...))))
```

However, if you have to do it all on the same syntactic level, you could do so by applying the macro recursively, along the following lines:

```
(define-syntax testclass
  (syntax-rules (public private)
    ((testclass public (var val) . rest)
     (testclass ((var val)) public . rest))
    ((testclass ((var val) ...) public (var1 val1) . rest)
     (testclass ((var val) ... (var1 val1)) public . rest))
    ((testclass lst public private . rest)
     (list (quote lst) (quote rest)))))
```

In order to make this more robust, you will have to add rules for empty public and private expressions.

Comment: What scheme implementation are you on? Im using chicken and was working on this problem on the IRC for it, we definitely were having no problem with using two ellipses, and others were able to use the first example

Comment: I.E. I was talking with the implementation designers and they say that it is syntactically correct.

Comment: and that its also defined behavior in r5rs

Comment: The usage of ellipsis is not defined R5RS/R7RS. See section 4.3.2 (coincidentally, both R5 and R7 have the same section number for this). If you want to write portable code, then it's better to split ellipses into 2 patterns.

Comment: @Anandamide I am using `guile 2.0.9.`

Comment: @Anandamide Do the implementors have anything to say about the problem? As far as I can see, the two examples are structurally identical. The only (possibly relevant) difference I can see is that the number of lists to be matched by the two ellipses is the same in example one, and different in example two.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but ive gotten the macro to work with other trivial examples of different numbers of private and public members, ive had many different trivial examples both work and not work

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Yeah I think thats the problem, because it does run in chicken